# How to build an odata service in node by json service

Tags: javascript, node.js, odata, sap-cap

We have a requirement of reading the service and convert it into odata. Our target system only understands odata and the source cannot deliver odata. So we are trying to build node service to facilitate the same.

I tried to use CAP (https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/get-started/) but it seems it can only work with persisted data.

It would be really helpful if you can provide any insight or any guidance for the same. We are aware that all odata operations we have to handle it at node middle layer.

Comment: explain your requirement more clearly: who is the consumer, who is the provider of data, give the sample of payload that data provider produces and the sample of format which consumer can accept

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, thanks for your reply. Provider is java web service from where we will be getting json payload and the target in some analytical dashboard which expects only odata formats. To be more precise we need to have metadata for service response and queries of odata should be applicable on the service response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by using existing npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-odata-server.

Regards,
Ammy

Answer (score 0):

For CAP, you can register `on` handlers for `entities` to override the standard behaviours.